# Does Java cache intermediate certificates fetched via AIA?

Tags: certificates, java

Java supports AIA chasing via the system property `com.sun.security.enableAIAcaIssuers` (which is disabled per default).  There is [some documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/security/java-pki-programmers-guide.htm#JSSEC-GUID-EB250086-0AC1-4D60-AE2A-FC7461374746) available but it is pretty slim regarding details.

I wonder what the performance impact of enabling this feature might be, especially for a long-running server application (which might take advantage of some caching) .  Will the JVM fetch the missing intermediates each time or are they cached?  Will it cache failed fetches?  It seems like at least certs retrieved via LDAP are cached but what about HTTP?

There is a related [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59614936/can-checkservertrusted-result-be-cached-for-x509trustmanager) which makes it sound like they aren't cached and one has to build an own cache.

The chasing itself is done via class `ForwardBuilder` (package `sun.security.provider.certpath`): First it seems like there is no caching because `getMatchingCerts` has a local `Set` which is filled with missing intermediates by `getCerts` (via `getMatchingCACerts`).  But `getCerts` calls `URICertStore.getInstance` which does use [some kind of cache](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/9a3e9542997860de79d07a4411b1007e9cd5c348/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/provider/certpath/URICertStore.java#L195).  I didn't dig further yet and look into the cache implementation but this seems like there is at least some caching done indeed (not only for LDAP).

Comment: Why would a server would use AIA? The server's certificates are fixed for all used domains and if client authentication is used usually only certificates of a small number of known CAs are accepted. So I don't see a use case where AIA would make sense here.

Comment: This is a pure programming question: Just look at source code. I suggest to close the question.

Comment: @Robert This is an enterprise application which talks to various 3rd party API endpoints (operated by different OUs or even other corps). Often the other sides don't deploy the certificates properly, ie. deploy only the leaf certificates without the intermediates. Adding a new endpoint often involves hunting down the proper intermediate and adding it to the Java trust store.

Comment: @mentallug I am not interested in the programming side but in the operational impact of enabling AIA chasing in an enterprise Java application. There is not definite answer to this question available on the internet (at least none that I could find).